# Linux write to file from java jar

Tags: java, javascript, linux

I am writing to text file from a Java jar executable. The jar generates the correct file but the permission of the file is set to root, therefore my other Javascript cannot read the file. It returns "Permission Denied" when I attempt to read the file via ajax. How can I fix the issue when creating the file in Java? I am currently running Java 1.6.

I did not have this issue when I was running the application within eclipse. Once I ported it over to jar permission changed to root access.

I am running the jar a

```
exec('java -jar writeToFile.jar');
```

The writing to file is standard

```
public void writeContents(String fp,String contents){
    try{
        BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fp));
        write.write(contents);
        write.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Failed to write to file " + fp + " error: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Writing to file works fine, it creates the file the correct directory and with the desired data, only difference between running it in eclipse and running it via jar is the file permission. The jar set the file to root.

Comment: Blind guess is that your WebServer does not have permission to access this file. Or that there is a lock on the file held by java code not closing it. Show us some code, or - better yet - create [SSCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: what user are you running your jar as? is it the same user that's running the web-server?

Comment: Yes it is the same user as the web-user is running in

Comment: I doubt Java will create the file as root-owned unless you are root when you execute it. I recommend confirming that you are the user you think you are by printing System.getProperty("user.name") from the same code that creates the file.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but with [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) class you can read and write attributes in files. May be there are some specifict attribute to your Operational System that must be set.

There are a setOwner method if you want to manipulate it too.